# Hello how to prevent this func from print 1 with the prime numbers array

Tags: c++

Hello i write this func to print the prime number from 2d array 
put when i enter for example 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 it print 1 2 3 5 7
how can i edit it to not

Comment: What's wrong with a simple `if` statement condition? What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Start by writting a simple function `bool is_prime(unsigned n)`. Then apply it on multiple values. You cannot debug anything with that kind of writing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your outer `if` statement to

```
if (count == 0 && o[i][j] != 1) {
    c[I] = o[i][j];
    I++;
    p++;
}
```

It would be easier to write a function that checks if a number is prime and call that function for each matrix element. Also there are more efficient ways to determine if a number is prime.

Answer (score 0):

I  added some comments to explain what is going on, but in advance, you are going to ignore '1' from the result list, so I added "if(o[i][j]!=1)", in the other hand, to find the prime list, if the first number is dividable, you will not need to count other numbers, so you can add "break;" in the for(...)

```
void FindPrime(int o[5][5]){
  int c[100];int I=0 ,count=0,p =0;
  int i,j,h;

for(i =0;i<5;i++)
{
    for(j =0;j<5;j++)
    {

        count =0;
      for(int k =2;k<o[i][j];k++)
      {
          if(o[i][j]% k == 0)
          {
             if(o[i][j]!=1)// Do not add 1 to the array
             {
                count++;
                // To make the function faster you can add "break;" here. If find the first dividable number, don't continue for 
             }
          }
      }
      if(count == 0)
      {
          c[I] = o[i][j];
          I++;
          p++;
      }

    }
}
for(int I =0;I<p;I++)
{
    h=c[I];
    cout<<" "<< h <<"  ";
}
cout<<"\n\n";
}
```